# pyadolc installation: avoiding "ImportError: No module named _adolc"

Tags: python, automatic-differentiation

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. After getting the requirements and following the pyadolc installation steps [here](https://github.com/b45ch1/pyadolc), I appended

*/home/my-name/pyadolc*

to the PYTHONPATH variable in my ~/.profile file.

Now, running

```
python -c "import adolc"
```

returns the following message:

```
ImportError: No module named _adolc
```

The message is the same no matter the location that I run the command.

The Github readme warns of this error when running this command from the root folder of pyadolc.

I tried reinstalling pyadolc, prepending the directory instead of appending it to the PYTHONPATH, and temporarily appending the directory to the PYTHONPATH via *sys.path.append()* without success. Any ideas of what is going wrong?

Comment: Which python version are you running?

Comment: sys.version returns '2.7.12 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40) \n[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]'

Answer (score 0):

As user b45ch1 pointed out in the [Github project page](https://github.com/b45ch1/pyadolc/issues/28), the following solved my problem:

1. Open ~/.profile and replace
   `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/my-name/pyadolc"`
   with 
   `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/my-name/pyadolc/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7"`, save and close.
2. Reboot